# How to cast the correct datatype for each column while parsing CSV most efficiently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, type-conversion

Perhaps this may seem trivial, but I am parsing multiple gigantic CSV files with 6,359,008 rows of data and they occupy 367.105 MiB disk space, merely loading the data without referencing already loaded information will take 2.9GiB RAM. So every bit of performance counts.

The CSV files have different number of columns, and the columns have different datatypes. But in each individual CSV file, the number of columns is the same for all rows, and also is the datatype of the fields in the same column.

The datatypes for the fields can be `int`, `float`, `bool` and `str`, and there are lots of omitted fields, in the CSV files they show up as `,,`, when loaded in Python these become `''`, in this case I want them to be cast to `None`. And there are some columns that contain junk data (that is the same for every row), I want to omit these columns.

My current method is to supply a list of data types to the parsing function, the function would then cast each field to the corresponding datatype using indexing, but unfortunately for this to work I need a dummy function that returns the string argument itself when no type casting is needed:

```py
import csv
from typing import Generator

def string(s: str) -> str:
    return s


def parse_csv(path: str, types: list) -> Generator:
    with open(path, mode='r', encoding='utf8') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        if len(next(reader)) != len(types):
            raise ValueError('number of columns is different from supplied number of types')
        
        functions = [(i, func) for i, func in enumerate(types) if func]
        for row in reader:
            yield [func(e) if (e := row[i]) else None for i, func in functions]
```

The following columns are the datatypes for the files that contain the absolute majority of the data:

```
IP_CITY_TYPES = [string, int, int, int, bool, bool, string, float, float, int]

IP_COUNTRY_TYPES = [
    string,
    int,
    int,
    int,
    bool,
    bool,
]

IP_ASN_TYPES = [string, int, string]
```

And the following columns are for the smaller files, but they also occupy Mebibytes of disk space:

```
CITIES_TYPES = [
    int,
    None,
    string,
    string,
    string,
    string,
    string,
    string,
    string,
    string,
    string,
    int,
    string,
    bool,
]

COUNTRIES_TYPES = [
    int,
    None,
    string,
    string,
    string,
    string,
    bool,
]
```

What is a better strategy to convert the datatypes?

---

Perhaps I didn't make it very clear. But now, know this, I cannot load all the data onto the RAM all at once with all the repeated combinations of some groups of columns.

I have made it very clear at the top of the question, it really takes multiple Gibibytes (2<sup>30</sup> = 1,073,741,824 bytes) just to load all the data without compression, that is, reading the data as CSV files, without type conversion, into Python `list`s, with all duplicating parts.

It takes around 3GiB RAM just to store all the data in RAM, and I have only 16GiB RAM. And this is without any processing involved. I fear if I process the data this way my RAM is going to be filled up and I would have to reboot my computer.

My data is the text dump of GeoLite2 IP geolocation database, it contains the information about the autonomous system, country and city of each IPv4 and IPv6 networks. The data is mainly split into 6 files, each file contains the information about (ASN | country | city) about (IPv4 | IPv6) networks, and I intend to combine three types of information about each version of IP networks into two SQLite3 tables.

The first column of the six files are all IP networks, in this case they are non-overlapping, the networks are unique, and the information about these networks, such as the columns for the information about the country, reappear quite a lot, they repeat, there are about a million networks for each version listed, and only 250 unique countries and 113,552 unique cities listed, so there is a huge amount of repetition and it would make sense to only store the unique combinations of the columns about each network and replace the columns with a reference to the unique combination.

More specifically I am turning each table into a list of two element tuples, the first column is a tuple consisting of two integers, they represent the start and end IP addresses of the networks, and the second column is an integer, it is the index of the unique combination of the rest of the columns.

I first convert the row from index 1 on into a `tuple`, then use the `tuple` as a key in a global variable that is a `dict`, check if it is present in the `dict`, if found, replace the columns with the integer value of the key as reference, else set the value corresponding to the key in the `dict` as the length of the `dict`, then replace the columns with the value.

This is accomplished with the following syntax:

```
TABLE = []
GROUPS = {}
for row in parse_csv('/path/to/file', DATATYPES):
    network, *group = row
    start, end = parse_network(network)
    TABLE.append(((start, end), GROUPS.setdefault(tuple(group), len(GROUPS))))
```

Comment: "I need a dummy function that returns the string argument itself" - So, you need `str`? Seriously, just use `str`, if you call it on a `str`, it does nothing, just returns the original `str` unchanged (it doesn't need to copy it, because `str` is immutable).

Comment: How do you know which _type_ a certain CSV is? And, you only have 5 types: the three IP types and then CITIES and COUNTRIES? Oh, also... how many files total? Oh, and what problem specifically have you encountered? I don't think you've actually stated a real problem; I've only seen you state a desire to avoid some potential performance issues.

Comment: Why do you think you need a better strategy, and what constitutes "better" for you? You talk about preserving memory, but the current strategy already does that effectively. You say performance is important, but I/O bound processing isn't really subject to massive improvements; the cost of the data conversions will typically be pretty tiny next to loading a (in real world cases) likely cold file from disk.

Comment: How about not using csv at all? Use parquet-tools to convert the file first. Add snappy compression to make it even smaller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first, if you use the MaxMind databases (which seems to be the case), then you can [use their own database format and their own API](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolocate-an-ip/databases). It seems you want to do the same thing manually, but SQLite will certainly be clearly less efficient than they specific database format, and you will spent a significant time to reimplement they API too (possibly less efficiently). CSVs are not provided for efficiency, but for convenience. In fact, their MMDB format takes only 68 MB instead of 370 MiB for the CSV for the GeoLite DB. This is 5.4x smaller!

> What is a better strategy to convert the datatypes?

**CPython strings should be avoided like the plague**. Indeed, a string reference in CPython takes 8 bytes and each string object typically takes 24 bytes + the size of the string with an additional overhead of the allocator. In the end, each 18-character-wide network CPython string will typically take 56-64 bytes! This means 340-390 MiB only for the network string column! The overhead is huge. If you store this in a 64-bit integer (4 bytes for the IPv4 network value and 1 byte for the mask), or even 2 separate integers (start-end ranges), then it takes only 48 MiB. This is 7-8 times smaller! You can do that in Pandas by using a user-defined decoding function like this:

```py
# Example of conversion function.
# It is inefficient. Please use Cython, or a C code so to do that more efficiently.
def net_to_int(val):
    m = re.match(r'(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)/(\d+)', val)
    int_val = int(m.group(1)) * 256**4 + int(m.group(2)) * 256**3 + int(m.group(3)) * 256**2 + int(m.group(4)) * 256**1 + int(m.group(5))
    return np.int64(int_val)

# The "network" column will use the function `net_to_int` 
# to parse each string so to convert it in an int64
converters = {'network' : net_to_int}

df = pd.read_csv(CSV_FILENAME, converters=converters)
```

Note this can significantly slow down the parsing time regarding the parsing function.

Moreover, using `int` and `float` generic types is also often not efficient. Please consider using **smaller types with a fixed size**. For example, you can use the `int32` and `float32` for most columns. They are twice smaller than the default types (`int64` and `float64`). A `int32` can store integers from -2_147_483_648 to 2_147_483_647. This is quite large. `float32` have a relative precision of about 6 digits. This should be enough for the latitude/longitude columns. The types of the columns can be specified in Pandas using the `dtype` parameter in the `read_csv` function. Note that you can use the `"Int32"` datatype instead of `"int32"` if some values are NA.

Note that Pandas store columns using **Numpy** which stores data in **compact native arrays**. Meanwhile, CPython lists are internally arrays of CPython objet pointers (typically 24+8 bytes per item). Thus, you should really avoid storing data into CPython objects unless you can store data in a much clever unstructured way.

> There are about a million networks for each version listed, and only 250 unique countries and 113,552 unique cities listed, so there is a huge amount of repetition

This is a **perfect use-case for the `"category"` Pandas datatype**. When Pandas parses a categorial column, it creates a *table of unique items* encountered so far and fill the final column with integers referencing the location of the item in the table. The integers are much smaller (4-byte on Windows) than string objets. The table should be small since the number of unique items is small in your case. A categorial column should only take 25 MiB in this case (on Windows). This is at least 8 times less than strings!

> I cannot load all the data onto the RAM all at once with all the repeated combinations of some groups of columns.

If this is still not enough, you can discard some columns with the `usecols` parameter when the CSV is read (for example the column "postal_code" might not very useful in your case or can be loaded later only if needed).

With such guidelines, I am able to load all the CSV files of the MaxMind GeoLite2 database in clearly less than 200 MiB (with 3.7 million lines for the biggest CSV file).

Note that Numpy can be used to search for the network address you want using `np.searchsorted` as long as addresses are sorted correctly (relatively fast -- runs in `O(log n)` time).

---

### Better data structures and file formats

Note that the best data structure for storing non-overlapping network addresses like this is a [**trie**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). This data structure is much more compact than storing all ranges, even using compact native integers. Each trie node is relatively small, especially the last ones (which are also the most numerous) : they can be compacted to only 2 bytes (start-end ranges, or the network mask). The last node can also contain metadata for the target IPv4 network (like the row ID of a database or even directly row data). This data structure is also very efficient to find network addresses very quickly in *constant time*.

This data structure is used by some huge database to store the information efficiently. Trie nodes can reference storage device directory when the information is so huge to even fit in RAM.

In practice, I think a dataframe should be good enough in your case. Besides, note that Pandas dataframe can be stored and read more efficiently from file format like **Parquet** or **Feather** (it takes respectively 4.8 and 4.3 times less space once compacted and stored on my disk and it can be reloaded in respectively about 0.3 and 0.2 second, that is 10-30 times faster than the initial CSV files).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't even know how your program works since the [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) function should'nt be used with the with statement.

If you can't use external packages and you have to only use pure Python, I don't see any other way than what you did. Maybe just use `string = str` to create an alias of `str` instead of creating a new function.

Otherwise, you can use specialized libraries for this kind of work, like pandas with [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#csv-text-files) :

```
import pandas as pd

IP_CITY_TYPES = [str, int, int, int, bool, bool, str, float, float, int]

# dtype is waiting a dict so {0: str, 1: int, ...}
# we can specify the name of the columns with {column_name: type, ...} 
# if the csv has column names (header is not None)
dtype = dict(enumerate(IP_CITY_TYPES))

# the number of rows to read at each iteration
# the biggest is he number the fastest is the reading but the more 
# memory it takes
chunksize = 1000

df_iterator = pd.read_csv('a.csv', dtype=dtype, chunksize=chunksize) # header=None if no header
```

and if you still want an iterator over the rows you can add:

```
from collections.abc import Iterator

def read_rows(df: Iterator[pd.DataFrame]) -> Iterator[list]:
    for chunk in df:
        for row_index, row in chunk.iterrows():
            yield list(row)

rows = read_rows(df_iterator)
```

Comment: Did you even read my question? I cannot load all the data unmodified into RAM, it would take way too much RAM, it literally takes around 3GiB RAM just to load the data as Python `list`s, and that is without any processing. In my data there are lots of repeating combinations of certain groups of columns, so I only store unique combinations of these columns in memory, and replace the groups of columns with integer reference to the unique groups, this cut down the RAM usage considerably, down to around 1GiB. Your code can't do that.

Comment: @ΞένηΓήινος: The code posted looks like it's loading in chunks of 1000 rows, it's not loading it all into RAM unmodified. I don't know if `pandas` has any optimizations for this case, but if it does, that's really the only way to balance your desire for high performance without blowing up memory; loading chunks and bulk converting each chunk, using the rows of that chunk one at a time until exhausted, then loading and bulk converting the next chunk. `pandas` just hides the complexity of that under-the-hood when you pass a `chunksize` argument.

Comment: For millions of rows, I think iterating w/Pandas could be slow: [DON'T iterate w/Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/246801).

Comment: For details with `pandas.read_csv` and a specified `chunksize`, you can see this related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-do-i-read-a-large-csv-file-with-pandas. But in summary @ShadowRanger is right, in my code df_iterator is an iterator that doesn't load anything except.. the iterator itself

Comment: Regarding the fact of not iterating over the rows yes @ZachYoung is right. Should I edit my answer? The goal of chunksize is to have an iterator which contains at each iteration a dataframe with the maximum that we can give to the ram. Then because Python is slow (and as a bonus to avoid complexity) it will always be preferable to use native pandas functions on these dataframes instead of loops as in my last piece of code suggests doing

Comment: @ZachYoung: That advice is for cases where you can afford the memory to load the whole dataframe at once. It's good advice for that case. It doesn't apply if the data is too large to fit in RAM. You can skip the iterating a row at a time, but the OP's requirements end up needing to load with some degree of laziness.